# Toggle between button states and perform function call in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I must admit I haven't quite grassped the concepts of Svelte yet. I made a component which purpose is to excecute a API-request of some sort. Each button component can have two or more buttons:

[Screenshot of "Button component"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orhiH.png)

When clicking a button in the buttongroup-component I want to do following:

1. Set clicked button to a state "active" so I can apply som kind of
   class to it.
2. Unset other button/-s with state "active".
3. Perform a custom function call

**Button component**

```
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <label>
        {labelTitle}
        {#if helpText}
            <Icon iconType="help" iconSize="small" iconTitle={helpText} />
        {/if}
    </label>
    <div class="buttons">
        {#each options as option, index}
            <button class={index === 0 ? 'selected' : ''} 
                value={option.id}
                name={option.name}
                on:click={setSelected}>
                    {option.name}
            </button>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Parent component**

`<ButtonGroup options={[{ id: 0, name: 'Option 1' }, { id: 1, name: 'Option 2' }]} labelTitle="Button label" />`

I my example i call setSelected on click, should I do it from the component itself or from the parent component?

I'm really lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your ButtonGroup a **Controlled Component** (it gets its current value through props and notifies changes) or make a **Uncontrolled Component** (stores its own state internally). Alternatively your component can support both, for example:

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    export let labelTitle = 'button label';
    export let options = []
    export let selected = 0

    function setSelected(e){
        const newValue = Number(e.target.value)

        selected = newValue

        dispatch('change', {value: newValue})
    }
</script>

<style>
    button.selected {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <label>
        {labelTitle}
    </label>
    <div class="buttons">
        {#each options as option, index}
            <button class={selected === index ? 'selected' : ''} 
                value={option.id}
                name={option.name}
                on:click={setSelected}>
                    {option.name}
            </button>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/12f5112852bd4dceb382578a4cfeed06?version=3.12.1